# Integrated webcam not detected/automatic slider not opening 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dell, webcam, shutter

when running cheese or zoom my integrated camera is not detected (dell latitude 9420, ubuntu 20.04). The computer has an automatic slider for the camera which is not opening (I cant open it manually), and everything works fine on windows (running dual boot). Just to be clear its not just that the image is black because the shutter is closed but also that the camera is just not detected in the first place.

I don't have a dev/video* and I have of course tried switching on/off the "webcam button" (fn+f9 in my case). I also checked in the bios and the camera is activated their. So I am really unsure what is going on. Please help.

I get the following output from cheese:

```
(cheese:7690): cheese-CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:7690): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:7690): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:7690): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:7690): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:7690): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:7690): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:7690): CRITICAL **: 18:32:59.057: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

Output from lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c08e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try checking the hardware user privileges in User and Groups administration and also try restoring your bios to defaults

Comment: does it work after a reboot (or a few reboots)? We ordered some 9420's last winter and they are shit... the camera module works sporadically under Linux...

Comment: No I didnt manage to make it work, after 4 month I simply gave up and am using an external cam. I know for a fact that the camera was working fine under windows (as I used windows for a few days on this very laptop before installing linux). Indeed the laptop seems to handle Linux quite poorly to be frank, quite a few things are unstable aside from just the camera not working like it should... If anyone has further tips please let me know.